# How to restrict request based on params in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to update my API to v5 (post /api/v5/registrations) and still want to support v1,v2,v3,v4. Under v5, I do not want process the create/update request if a params with registration[:secret_token] is missing from request body.

how to do this?
Invalid request=  `{:user=>{:name=>XYZ, :roll_number=>1}}`

Valid Request:  `{:user=>{:name=>XYZ, :roll_number=>1, :secret_token=>"DSGASDFG34534"}}`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add following code in `application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :authorize!

private

def authorize!
 head :forbidden unless params[:secret_token].present?
end
```